# Pulling specific values from a form with a checkbox to select rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a form that has multiple rows generated from rows from a table query. Each row has text boxes and drop down boxes that are pre-populated from a table query. This allows the users to make changes to the values in the row before submitting, if necessary. However, only the rows with checkboxes that are selected should be inserted into the table.

So, if I have 15 rows and only 10 checkboxes are selected, how do I only insert the 10 rows with the checkboxes and ignore the array values for the data coming from rows without checkboxes selected?

```
WHILE ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>

<input type="hidden" name="RB_TG_ID[]" value="<? echo $row['RB_TG_ID'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="state_id" value="<? echo $state_id ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rpt_id" value="<? echo $rpt_id ?>">
 <tr>

<td class="normal"><input type="checkbox" name="CB[]" value="1"></td>
<td class="normal"><? echo $row['TG'] ?></td>
<td class="normal">
  <SELECT NAME="TS[]">
    <option SELECTED VALUE="<? echo $row['TS'] ?>"><? echo $row['TS'] ?>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td class="normal"><? echo $row['assignment'] ?></td>
<td>
  <SELECT NAME="access[]">
    <option SELECTED VALUE="<? echo $row['FP'] ?>"><? echo $row['FP'] ?>     </option>
    <option value="PTT">PTT</option>
    <option value="Full-Time">Full-Time</option>
    <option value="Sched"> Scheduled</option>
   </select>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Here is what the form looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF79X.jpg

As you can see from the form, all of the lines can be modified by the user and all will send their values on POST, except for the checkbox, which only send a value of "1" if checked. I am only interesting in the line if that first checkbox is checked. All other lines and the information can be igored and will not be entered into the database. So, if I check the first three rows and the least one leaving several blank in the middle, I can do a print_r on the arrays and I get this:

```
Variables: 
00
1
CB: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 ) 
TS: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 [5] => 2 [6] => 2 [7] => 2 ) 
TG: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 25 [2] => 7 [3] => 2 [4] => 31 [5] => 38 [6] => 65 [7] => 66 ) 
Access: Array ( [0] => PTT [1] => [2] => [3] => Full-Time [4] => PTT [5] => PTT [6] => PTT [7] => PTT )
```

the first line with the 00 and the second line with the 1 are fine because they will be looped in on every inserted row.

But, how do I only insert the results that correlate with checking the checkbox of the line I selected. As you can see, although I checked four boxes and the variable named "CB" only shows four values, the rest of the variables show 8 values. How do I ignore the those values and make the array pointers line up for looping into an INSERT? The checlbox seems to be my problem becuase it is only sending a value if checked. So, I can't do an if/then for a "1" value. I tried sending the CB[] checkbox value from a hidden field before the actual checkbox field, but it just added another element to the array. Meaning, if there were 8 checkboxes and I checked them all, I would end up with 16 elements alternating betweens 1's and 0's.

Comments below are asking for MySQL code, but I haven't written any yet, other than to display the form in the example in the image. I don't know how to organize the arrays to the data lines up for entry into the database. I figured once it was lined up one for one, I would write a FOREACH loop to run the insert query for as many lines as were selected by the user.

Comment: where's the mysql for this?

Comment: You can filter the php POST array before inserting but need to see your code.

Comment: Have I shown enough code and examples or do you need me to add more?

Comment: Thank you, rocknrollcanneverdie. Your example is working beautifully and you provided enough sample code that I was able to get this up and running with zero issues. The data is inserting directly into the database exactly the way I need it to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor the form first. If you group each line together you can match the values in each row easily. An example:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = ...) :
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="data[<?= $i ?>][CB]"></td>
        <td><select name="data[<?= $i ?>][TS]">...</select></td>
        <td><select name="data[<?= $i ?>][access]">...</select></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

Or instead of a counter ($i) you can use an id, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[<?= $row['RB_TG_ID'] ?>][CB]">
```

After submit check each row in $_POST['data'] and save only the records with the checkbox on:

```
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $row) {
    // If the checkbox is on
    if (isset($row['CB'])) {
        // Sanitize n' save this row
        // $ts = $row['TS'];
        // $access = $row['access'];        
    }
}
```